# C++ confused with scope and declarations

Tags: c++, instantiation

I already posted another question regarding structs versus classes. I believe I got good feedback, so I went back to work on my code.
Here is what confused me (maybe it is childish ;) )

I need to Have a class (or struct doesnt really mind) that is called cPoint, and it just defines a Point in space with X, Y coordinates.
 from it all shape-classes will derive. So for cRectangle, that is a class for rectangles, the cPoint will be used as a base element.
To instantiate a Rectangle, the caller must provide the coordinates of 2 points, that will be the rectangles UpperLeft & LoowerRight corners respectively.
What I want the cRectangle constructor to do, is to instantiate these two points, as it **own private points** and use them to define the rectangle, do calculations etc. These two points should not be visible to public scope, so a caller can't change them directly.
Here is an example(wrong obviously) for what I try to do:

```
class cPoint
{
    public:
    int X,Y;
    cPoint();
    cPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        X=x;
        Y=y;
    }
};

class cRectangle
{
friend class cPoint;
public:
    Rectangle(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2)    //the constructor of cRectangle
        {
            ul(x1,y1);
            dr(x2,y2);
        }
    unsigned int area()
        {
            return((dr.X-ul.X) * (dr.Y-ul.Y));//example function that uses ul,dr
        }           
private:    
    cPoint ul;  //uP lEFT point
    cPoint dr;  //dOWN Right point
};
```

The error that i get is *" Error    1 no match for call to '(cPoint) (int&, int&)' "*

Thank you

Comment: You have to use initialization lists to initialize member variables or call parent constructors. The syntax you are using there is trying to call an `operator()(int, int)` on `cPoint` which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* use initilization list */
Rectangle(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2) : ul(x1,y1), dr(x2,y2)
{
}
```

Your code won't compile because here

```
Rectangle(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2)    //the constructor of cRectangle
        {
            ul(x1,y1);
            dr(x2,y2);
        }
```

you wanted to call `operator(int,int)` on instances of `cPoint` class and definition of this operator has been not provided.

Answer (score 1):

Once you enter the body of a constructor, all members are initialized and you can only assign to them and everything else that you can do to a living object.

By the point you attempt this

```
        ul(x1,y1);
        dr(x2,y2);
```

`ul` and `dr` have already been default initialized (default constructor is the one that's called if you don't explicitly initializer members - read on). When compiler sees these two lines, it looks like you're trying to call overloaded `operator()` that doesn't exist, so it naturally reports an error.

To initialize members, use constructor initialization list:

```
Rectangle(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2)
    : ul(x1,y1), dr(x2,y2) // <-- initialization list
                           // using cPoint::Cpoint(int, int) constructor
{
    // note, empty body
}
```